# Error while exporting to unity

Tags: animation, export

I am relatively new in blender, I learned how to use it last week so I am pretty much a noob. After finishing a character (incluiding the animations)that I was making for unity, when I exported it, it just got completely messed up and all the parts were ditributed everywhere. looking at my blender character I notice this orange points everywhere and I think this had something to do with the problem. Is this fixable? shall I start from 0? Help please[image: the wierd dots are inside the red circles]

Comment: Those orange dots are origin points check your outliner to see what they are and delete them if they are not needed, maybe you have objects in your scene without any mesh detail it's just like an empty object since your new to Blender maybe accidentally created these during the modeling process.

Comment: Looks like you might have repositioned the meshes in edit mode and the object's origin stayed where you originally created them. You can move the origin to the correct position, you don't need to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Object > Origin > Origin to geometry. The orange dots are the center of your mesh, but need to actually be where the center of the mesh is. Credit to the people in the comments.